# Samba share with Windows - "You require permission from <MACHINE>\nobody to make changes to this file"

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I have setup Samba to share a folder "home/*username*/raid" from my ubuntu server

I can access the folder from my windows machine windows but cannot delete or change files

The folder permissions are set to 777 and the share is setup in smb.conf as follows

```
[Shared Folder]
path = /home/<username>/raid
valid users = <username>
read only = no
guest ok = yes
writeable = yes
```

When I try to delete a file with the windows machine I get the error "You require permission from MACHINE\nobody to make changes to this file"

Comment: Could you post the log files of Samba? I suspect you are connected as 'guest'?  Also try with `guest ok = no` to force user prompt.

Comment: is there a simple command to see the log files? I have tried guest ok = no and restarted samba but no difference (first time I went to the folder from windows I did have to put in username and password)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this now. It turned out when I set the permissions for the folder I had written

```
sudo CHMOD 777 /path-to-folder
```

I needed to write

```
sudo CHMOD -R 777 /path-to-folder
```

to ensure the subdirectories' permissions were also set

Comment: **Warning** before you try this, you'd be aware this grants ALL permissions to ALL users.

Comment: That's... certainly one way to solve this problem lol